# JSON and array structure typeahead

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to create a json file from an sql query, and search this json using twitter typeahead. However the json format doesn't look correct.

The json needs to be in a certain format for typeahead like below;

```
['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California' ...];
```

However my json is in the following format;

```
["{\"title\":\"Item 1\"}","{\"title\":\"Item 2\"}","{\"title\":\"Item 3\"}"
```

Newbie to php/sql/json I'm sure there is something really obvious I'm missing or doing wrong. Maybe I should be using a `foreach` and not `while`? I am able to echo out the `$titles` so I now the query is working.

If somebody cold point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

**My code so far;**

```
$sql = ("SELECT title FROM publication");

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = json_encode($row);
    $titles = json_encode($data);
    echo $titles;//for testing
}

file_put_contents('titles.json', $titles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're over-encoding your data and
2. you're not including the data you actually want.

Put the data you want into the array and JSON-encode the whole thing only at the end:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['title'];
}

file_put_contents('titles.json', json_encode($data));
```

Comment: thanks for this @deceze however nothing is being written to my `titles.json` file whereas it was before, it's empty whenever I open it. Whenever I `echo json_encode($data);` it looks good though so that's a start!

Answer (score 1):

You are performing json_encode twice which should not be the case.

Instead the Code should be like below:

```
$data[] = $row;
$titles = json_encode($data);
```

or simply

```
$titles = json_encode($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `json_encode` once

```
    $data[] = $row; /*$data[] = json_encode($row);*/
```

and write this:

```
 $titles = json_encode($data);
```

**OR**

```
$titles = json_encode(array_values($data));  /*You may need to use this to get exact output*/
```

After `while` loop

Answer (score -1):

You are inserting associative array to your json `array('title'=>'sometitle')` but you only need that title.
The solution is to only save the title value from the db resulting row to the array:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row['title'];
    echo json_encode($data); // dont encode twice
}
file_put_contents('titles.json', json_encode($data));
```